# Spotify crashing on Kubuntu 16.04 after few minutes

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, spotify

for something like a month spotify has been crashing after running for few minutes (3-4 minutes). The crash doesn't occur when I launch spotify from command line. How can I solve it?

Please find crash log attached.

Regards,
Artur

Comment: Did you forget to upload the crash log?

Comment: true, I forgot :/ And now I cannot reproduce the issue even though up till now it was 100% reproducible